# Is there a way to get an object from the context if I only have the entitysetname and the value of a unique property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am trying to write a synchronisation procedure. I have a log table of my changes to the local database and want to apply them to a remote database.

For each log entry I need to find the corresponding record in the remote database, given that I know the entityset name and the value of a unique field called RowId. RowId is not the primary key.

I have tried putting the following inside my context class, but it means I have to edit the code every time I add a new domain class.

Is there a way to write the procedure without using a giant switch statement?
I a method similar to Entity Framework's GetObjectByKey method

Here is the giant switch statement I want to replace

```
public object GetObjectByRowId(string EntitySetName, Guid RowId)
{
    switch ("People")
    {
        case AppDataEnum.People:
            return People.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == RowId);
            break;
```

etc..

I might be able to solve it by making all the entities implement an IRowId interface, but I am hoping that EF has an inbuilt way

I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013379/can-i-use-entitykey-with-fields-that-are-not-keys)

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766450/generics-and-entity-framework-how-do-i-return-a-different-type-depending-on-a-c) may help.  Although in that scenario many types are being extracted from the same table.  In my scenario many tables have the RowId field.

```
Public Class Person : LoggedEntity
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Public Class Organisation : LoggedEntity
    {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

```
Public Class LoggedEntity
{  [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but the Guid is not the primary key

Comment: Do you know name of property? Do all entities have that property?

Comment: Yes I know the name of the propery, it is RowId

Comment: @kirsteng all your entities have `RowId` property?

Comment: yes, They have an identity key called Id, and a Guid called RowID

Comment: I am synchronising data between 2 databases , and the objects in the remote database must be found using RowID

Comment: i.e instead of calling Context.GetObjectByKey()  I need to call a function like Context.GetObjectByRowID(Type, RowID)
How do I write that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing the answer involved Generics, I finally got

```
    public TEntity GetEntityByRowId<TEntity>( Guid rowId) where TEntity : LoggedEntity
    {
        return Db.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == rowId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your unique key consists of a tuple of type + unique identifier. If I'm understanding your question correctly, the row ID is unique for each given type, but two objects of differing types may have the same row ID.

You can override GetHashCode and construct a unique hash based on the combination of type and the row ID. How to come up with a good hash function is beyond the scope of this question, but as a very stupid solution, you can do something like (Type.Name + RowId).GetHashCode()

That would return the hash code of the string concatenated from the two. From that point onwards, you can just put everything in a HashSet and have retrieve the objects efficiently.

If efficiency is not a concern, just track the objects of each type in their own list and when looking for a particular type, just iterate over the list of objects with the type of interest looking for the specific RowId.

Comment: The RowId is a guid, so two objects of differing types should not have the same RowId

Comment: How do I get the list given I have the entityset name?